# Does EC2 Network Performance matter inside a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-vpc

If I'm just communicating inside my VPC only, like from a web server to a database server, does the Network Performance of an EC2 server still have an affect?

It sounded like it was more for outbound traffic to the internet or to other parts of AWS. Just communicating inside my own VPC seems like it shouldn't matter a whole lot. am I right?

Comment: No. You could setup listeners to check for latency etc. to test though!

Comment: Type of ec2 instance does matter in determining howmuch network bandwidth is available to you. Look at the following documentation on benchmarking on aws netwrok bandwidth. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you and the instance you wish to communicate with just by pure chance end up on the same physical host then probably not, but the chance of this happening is extremely unlikely.

In every AZ you have multiple data centres of deliberately unknown size, shape and each is separated from each other by enough distance to make AWS feel comfortable.

So if you fire up 2x t2.small instances in ap-southeast-2a at the exact same time for example, you cannot be sure what data centre they have started up in, and even if they are in the same DC chances are you still will have many hops between you as you make your way around that DC.

There is a lot of traffic in a DC, even just internal. When you select a Instance Type you are receiving a product that may exceed what it says on the box on some occasions and only where possible, but AWS will only commit to the specifications promised for that instance type.

Unless you are purchasing an instance with guaranteed throughput, assume Low, Medium and High represent prioritization, not a specific guaranteed bandwidth.